# Embedding a Google Drive folder in an Iframe throws error 403, when not logged into a Google account

Tags: html, iframe, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I am attempting to embed a Google Drive folder (which is set to `"Anyone on the Internet with the link can view"` into a webpage, through an iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=THE_FOLDER_ID#list" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

As long as the user has a Google logged-in session within the browser, this will work, whilst when the user is disconnected from a Google account, an error 403 will be thrown:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
The folder will appear in an incognito window when loaded using the syntax `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/THE_FOLDER_ID?resourcekey=A_RESOURCE_KEY&usp=sharing`

Comment: Can you share the link to the folder you're working with? Or can you confirm that you're able to see the folder in an incognito window? Try to do this only with the link you generate from Drive, not through your website. Also, is this a folder from a Google Workspace account?

Comment: The folder will not open in incognito which is weird.. And yes this is Workspace account

Comment: Where can I send the link to you privately?

Comment: Can you go to the folder in the Drive UI, click on "Share" and let me know what option is selected below "General access"? I made a quick test from a Google Workspace account as well and have no issues viewing the folder if I'm not signed in to a Google account. The folder access was "Anyone with the link", if you already have this option selected, can you test with a different folder? I also tried with a folder inside a Shared Drive in case you're trying that too but still I can view the folder without signing in.

Comment: Also, have you made any sharing permissions update in the Admin console?

Comment: A quick update: the folder is visible in an incognito window, but it will throw an error when embedded in an iframe element. And no I haven't made in changes in the Admin console. Maybe there has been a change in Google security settings when content is loaded in an Iframe?

Comment: Look if the file URL contains a resource key and try this way `<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDERID&resourcekey=RESOURCEKEY#list" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>`? Or this way: `<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/a/YOURDOMAIN.COM/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID#list" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>`?

Comment: The first proposed solution throws an error 404, the second one 403